# In an array constant with psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my psql query :

```
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces,nb_room,is_fiber,codes_insee) as (
   values (0,0,false,('95018','75018'))
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
     on_plan_buy pbuy
INNER JOIN
    card_fiche fiche
    ON pbuy.uuid = fiche.ad_uuid
INNER JOIN
    myconstants const
    ON true
WHERE pbuy.code_insee IN ('95018','75018')
    AND pbuy.price <= 99999999 AND pbuy.price >= 0
    AND CASE WHEN const.nb_pieces = 0 THEN pbuy.piece > 0 ELSE pbuy.piece = const.nb_pieces END 
    AND CASE WHEN const.nb_room = 0 THEN pbuy.chambre > 0 ELSE pbuy.chambre = const.nb_room END 
    AND CASE WHEN const.is_fiber = false THEN true ELSE fiche.fiber = true END
LIMIT 100;
```

It works fine.

But i would like to use my constant:

```
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces,nb_room,is_fiber,codes_insee) as (
   values (0,0,false,('95018','75018'))
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
     on_plan_buy pbuy
INNER JOIN
    card_fiche fiche
    ON pbuy.uuid = fiche.ad_uuid
INNER JOIN
    myconstants const
    ON true
WHERE pbuy.code_insee IN const.codes_insee
    AND pbuy.price <= 99999999 AND pbuy.price >= 0
    AND CASE WHEN const.nb_pieces = 0 THEN pbuy.piece > 0 ELSE pbuy.piece = const.nb_pieces END 
    AND CASE WHEN const.nb_room = 0 THEN pbuy.chambre > 0 ELSE pbuy.chambre = const.nb_room END 
    AND CASE WHEN const.is_fiber = false THEN true ELSE fiche.fiber = true END
LIMIT 100;
```

And now it doesn't works.

Any idea how to use correctly the const.codes_insee ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a `record` with `('95018','75018')` for `codes_insee` where you would like to specify a set of values to search using the `IN` operator. However this operator does not work with this type. Instead, you can change the data type to an `array`, allowing you to add more filters in the future if you desire, and use the array functions. I've used `array_position` to determine if the value is in the array. See below

```sql
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces,nb_room,is_fiber,codes_insee) as (
   values (0,0,false,string_to_array('95018,75018',','))
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
     on_plan_buy pbuy
INNER JOIN
    card_fiche fiche
    ON pbuy.uuid = fiche.ad_uuid
INNER JOIN
    myconstants const
    ON true
WHERE 
    array_position(const.codes_insee,cast(pbuy.code_insee as text)) > -1
    AND pbuy.price <= 99999999 AND pbuy.price >= 0
    AND CASE WHEN const.nb_pieces = 0 THEN pbuy.piece > 0 ELSE pbuy.piece = const.nb_pieces END 
    AND CASE WHEN const.nb_room = 0 THEN pbuy.chambre > 0 ELSE pbuy.chambre = const.nb_room END 
    AND CASE WHEN const.is_fiber = false THEN true ELSE fiche.fiber = true END
LIMIT 100;
```

#### Reference

- [Postgresql Array Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of IN please try exists:

```
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces,nb_room,is_fiber,codes_insee) as (
   values (0,0,false,('95018','75018'))
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
     on_plan_buy pbuy
INNER JOIN
    card_fiche fiche
    ON pbuy.uuid = fiche.ad_uuid
INNER JOIN
    myconstants const
    ON true
WHERE 
    pbuy.price <= 99999999 AND pbuy.price >= 0
    AND CASE WHEN const.nb_pieces = 0 THEN pbuy.piece > 0 ELSE pbuy.piece = const.nb_pieces END 
    AND CASE WHEN const.nb_room = 0 THEN pbuy.chambre > 0 ELSE pbuy.chambre = const.nb_room END 
    AND CASE WHEN const.is_fiber = false THEN true ELSE fiche.fiber = true END
and exists
(
select 1 from myconstants  where pbuy.code_insee = myconstants.codes_insee  
)
LIMIT 100;
```